# Create a web site for only certain users

Tags: wordpress

I am starting to code a new wordpress theme for my project.

However, I only want users who log in to my site to see the content. If a user is not logged in, I only want them to see a login form. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin called [Restricted Site Access](http://wordpress.org/plugins/restricted-site-access/) which will restrict access to your website.

Comment: is there any filter / docs or somethşng else about this. I really dont want to use any plugin

Comment: Yes. When you login a cookie is stored/a session is started. You could look for that and if you don't find it then redirect the user to the login page, if you do find one then do nothing.